# MySQL too slow with queries when huge amount of entries, good alternatives?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, r, sqlite

I have 20.000.000 Entries in a MySQL table. Now sending and recieving the following query takes 12 seconds for each ID in my for loop!

```
SELECT x FROM clicks WHERE urlID = 1234567"
```

The table looks like:

```
x     urlID 
3     2523523
5     2236236
2     6363463
6     4574747
1     2523523
```

I have to check 1 million on these urlIDs. So this would take me 12 seconds * 1 million = 130 days. A bit too much. So how can I speed up my MySQL or do you know workaround to make it faster? OR even other databases that are faster. I just need this constructs of searching by the ID and geting the x value. It's pretty simple.

I have already tested:

- editing "my.ini" files to make MYSQL faster testing with only 1 million entries which also needed 1 second, so it's linear I can say by the moment
- CPU/RAM there is always min. 20% free which isn't used at all
- latest MySQL version 5.5
- also tested in SqLite which was 20% even slower then the MySQL test

Please give me some ideas. Already watched out for some ideas on simliar threads but they didn't help me.

### 2. Example

Let's say the above table is called "clicks". Now we have another table named "test". This table constist of:

```
sessionID   urlID     performance
1234515     2523523   
2523652     2236236
3643463     6363463
4574747     4574747
5858585     2342352
```

What I want to to have in the end is that in "performance" is a value that say how good an urlID is. So it shall be serached for an urlID and lookings up the "x"-values in the clicks table. Now I need to count them and summing them up. Now writing "summing/count" as float into the "performance" column. Is this possible with only MySQL? Or do I really need to perform this in PHP, R or whatever?

### My R function

```
fnc.generateDiff_result <- function(urlIDs) { 
  string <- dbGetQuery(conRMySQL, sprintf("%s%s","SELECT diff_012 FROM clicks WHERE urlID = ",urlIDs))
  test <- (sum(complete.cases(string)))
  if (test==0){
    return(0)
  }
  numberOfEntrys <- (sum(complete.cases(string)))
  sumOfEntrys <- sum(string)
  return(sumOfEntrys/numberOfEntrys)
}
```

Comment: It's not MySQL's fault. `SELECT x FROM clicks WHERE urlID = 123456`  without indexing on a big data set will surely take that much time. First up place some proper indexes to stop full table scan. MySQL will eat `12.000.000` records for a dinner if the database schema is right

Comment: Look for a way to avoid running that query inside a loop.

Comment: @dan even a signle query needs that 12 seconds, I also have checked this of course

Comment: @hanky: Okay I indexed the "urlID" and tested again on my 20 million entries. Now improved from the 12 seconds to 1 seconds. But still not good enough for me =/

Comment: Atleast that tells you it was not MySQL's issue :) See in less than 10 minutes and with one single improvement you are down to 1 second. Work on it for a day and optimize and you will get down to milliseconds

Comment: Well I did not find anything that helps me directly. And I'm also not the best MySQL dude you can think of. Do you know more techniques. I also have primary keys in there. And is it whise to index some more ID columns in there?

Comment: Besides the indexing, the other advice you received revolved around the fact that you are looking up only one urlID at a time in a loop. That's generally a really inefficient way to do things. Instead, retrieve multiple urlIDs  using an `IN` clause. Processing them in memory will be much faster than loading one at a time from disk.

Comment: @joran: I understand the concept of IN but I can't figure out how to use it for this example. Maybe if you find some time to help my with a code example would be awesome.

Comment: You haven't shown us anything to actually help with, so no, I'm not inclined to spend much time on it.

Comment: Post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE clicks\G`.

Comment: @joran: No - 'IN' is not the solution - with a million values to lookup, it needs a join.

Comment: @tadman: Well here you got it. Hope it helps: CREATE TABLE `clicks` (
 `sessionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `diff_012` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `diff` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `units` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `counter` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `urlID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`sessionID`,`units`,`urlID`),
 KEY `sessionID` (`sessionID`),
 KEY `diff_012` (`diff_012`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: @symcbean Sorry, misunderstood you comment. Reading too fast. I missed the 1mill values part.

Comment: @joran: and not even simple division can be done in MySQL? So let's say I minimize my querys. And instead of getting back a single urlID response, how can I get back many of them and still make sure to get them sperated.

Comment: You need an index on `urlID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) MySQL provides. Using [AVG()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) you can calculate the "performance" of all `urlID`s with just one query.

> **AVG([DISTINCT] expr)**
>
> Returns the average value of ***expr***. The ***DISTINCT*** option can be used to
>   return the average of the distinct values of ***expr***.

```
SELECT urlID, AVG(diff_012) AS performance
FROM clicks
GROUP BY urlID;
```

You also can store the result directly into a table.

```
INSERT INTO test
    SELECT urlID, AVG(diff_012) AS performance
    FROM clicks
    GROUP BY urlID;
```

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for. I did some extra customizations and finally got this what worked pretty well for me: INSERT INTO t_performance
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sessionID) , urlID, AVG(diff_012 + 0.000000) , count(diff_012) 
FROM clicks
GROUP BY urlID

Answer (score 2):

> takes 12 seconds for each ID in my for loop!

If you are creating and running SELECT statements in a loop then you're doing it wrong. Fixing this will give you your biggest performance win.

You've not provided *any* details of how the database is configured nor the underlying schema. Do you have an index? If not, then add one (for this query you want one on (urlid,x) *in that order*)

Next, go get a good book on MySQL performance - O'Reilly's High Performance MySQL is good - and a simple book on relational database. Read them and apply the knowledge - you should be doing a join with a table containing the 1 million data items you're looking for or using code with handler sockets to carry out the join in your application.

Comment: Yes one single SELECT lasts 12 seconds and now with the indexing just 1 seconds. It has nothing to do with the for-loop so far. I just tried so say how to SELECT work automatically line by line. That actually works great but as I said above it's too slow.

Comment: @kwoxer You're missing the point. Running one select statement for each value is SLOW. The for loop is you largest remaining problem. Listen to symcbean.

Comment: Yes sure I need to reduce the requests. But as I already said I need to decide each response I get from the database. And getting all data at one time will blow up my RAM. An idea? You can also find my R function above now.

Comment: When I tried to query multiple Select like:

SELECT (SELECT diff_012 FROM clicks WHERE urlID = 49344912),(SELECT diff_012 FROM clicks WHERE urlID = 53105089)

I got the error:  "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row". So this can't work, too. It also lasted the same time as if I would query 2 times...

Comment: @kwoxer: learn some SQL - `SELECT diff_012 FROM clicks WHERE urlID IN (49344912, 53105089,....)` - but this only scales up to a hundred or so literals - after that it's more efficient to insert the values in another table and do a JOIN